# ember-cli bootstrap collapse need help on code

Tags: ember-cli

I am trying to get Bootstrap "collapse.js" to work with a button click. It will hide but not show on button click. This is in the brocfile.js:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
'ember-cli-bootstrap-sass': {
'importBootstrapJS': ['affix','collapse']
}
});
```

and this is what I have in the template.hbs:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Link with href
</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Button with data-target
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
   Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help?  Am I missing something.  I am using ember-cli version 2.5 and ember-cli-bootstrap-sass.

Appreciate help.

Comment: So, what's the question? How to make it show on button click?

Comment: Yes, it's hidden, but when I click button, it does not show. Appreciate your help.